# Does Dart have a widget library?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

Looking into Dart a year later and I don't see any comprehensive widget library. I saw KevMoo's Widget.Dart project on GitHub but none of the widgets actually seem to work. I currently use AngularJS for my projects and have a great set of libraries such as Boostrap UI, and ng-grid which allow me to be productive without recreating the wheel.  Anything like this in Dart?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are widget libraries but they are mostly work in progress.

### for Angular2 Dart

- [angular2-material](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_material)
- [ng2-strap](https://github.com/luisvt/ng2-strap)

### for Angular.dart 1.x

- [angular.dart.ui](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui) a Dart port of Angular UI Polymer
- [AngularPrime-Dart](http://showcase.angularfaces.com/AngularPrimeDart/)
- [Angular.dart.material](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.material/)

### for Polymer.dart >= 1.0.0

- [polymer_elements](https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements) Dart
  port of JS https://elements.polymer-project.org/
- [bwu_datagrid](https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid) Dart port of JS SlickGrid

### for Polymer.dart <= 0.16.x

- [core-elements](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/core_elements)
- [paper-elements](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements)
- [bwu_datagrid](https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid) Dart port of JS SlickGrid
- [Pixelate](https://github.com/donny-dont/Pixelate)
- [HtmlElements](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html_components)
- [Spark widgets](https://github.com/dart-lang/spark/tree/master/widgets)

### WebGL

- [RöckDöt for Dart](http://rockdot.sounddesignz.com/template/)

### others

- [MDL (Material Design Lite)](http://www.material-design-lite.pub/)
- [DWT](http://dartwebtoolkit.com/)
- [Bootjack](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bootjack)
- [Rikulo UI](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rikulo_ui)
- [Rikulo UXL](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rikulo_uxl)

### DEPRECATED

- [polymer_ui_elements](https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements) Dart port of JS polymer-ui-elements
- [core_elements](https://github.com/bwu-dart/core_elements) Dart port of JS core-elements (just started)

and probably others

Comment: I will mark this as the answer.  It looks like people are starting to develop widgets for it, but they aren't quite there yet.  I use datagrids all over the place in my business apps so I may have to wait for the dart community to become more mature.

Comment: Widget.dart like package is e.g. Bootjack (Bootstrap rewritten to Dart)

Comment: Could you please update this answer (if there's anything to be added or marked as deprecated)?

Answer (score 1):

Another one worth mentioning:
http://www.material-design-lite.pub